# ASP.NET master page logo renders last and takes a while to load

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, jpeg

My asp.net web app uses a master page which contains an 8k jpg of the company logo.  Whenever I load a page or do a refresh, all of the non-master page html renders first, then the master page logo is shown, pushing all the html down a few lines.  It's very annoying.  Is there anything I can do to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add width= and height= attributes matching the image size to the img tag.